# Query on MAX on date column, and COUNT of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I performed the following query with cte's, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way of writing the code, maybe with subqueries? I'm retrieving everything from one table SALES, but I'm using 3 columns: AgentID, SaleDate, and OrderID.

```
WITH RECENT_SALE AS(
    SELECT AGENTID,(
    SALEDATE,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AGENTID ORDER BY SALEDATE DESC) AS RN
 FROM SALES
)
,
 COUNT_SALE AS (
    SELECT AGENTID,
 COUNT(ORDERID) AS COUNTORDERS
 FROM SALES
)

  SELECT RECENT_SALE.MRN, 
 SALEDATE, 
 COUNTORDERS

 FROM RECENT_SALE
 INNER JOIN COUNT_SALE ON RECENT_SALE.AGENTID = COUNT_SALE.AGENTID;
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get JUST the most recent row? Or just order them by SALEDATE descending?

Comment: Are you trying to select just the most recent `SALEDATE` and then count how many of those there are by `AGENTID`?

Comment: The second CTE is syntactically incorrect, so this code will simply return a syntax error.

Comment: I just want the most recent row, but I would like to get the total number of orders for each sales person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're just trying to get the total number of sales per agent as well as the date of his or her most recent sale? If I understand your structure correctly (and I may not), then it seems pretty straightforward. I'm guessing `orderid` is the primary key of `SALES`?

```
SELECT agentid, MAX(saledate) AS saledate -- Most recent sale date
     , COUNT(orderid) AS countsales -- total sales
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY agentid;
```

There does not seem to be any need for CTEs or subqueries here.

Comment: Thank you, I think my mind was just overlooking the simplest case and really overdoing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT 
    saledate,
    AGENTID, 
    count(orderid) over(partition by AGENTID order by saledate)
 FROM SALES
 group by  
    saledate,
    AGENTID
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this out. I wound up with a table like the one below, but it's not giving me the total number of sales matched up with the most recent sale date. <br> AGENT ID    SALEDATE         COUNT
<br>
001               2000-02-27         1
<br>
002               2002-01-28         1
<br>
002               2002-02-01         2
<br>
002               2003-03-01         3  

003               2001-01-20         1